# Why i can not input set in my code?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

When writing out a property in visual studio, the IDE autocompletes the wrong text and interrupts my flow.

```
class Person
{
    private int age;
    public int Age;
{
   AppDomainSetup //

}
```

`AppDomainSetup` is given when I've typed `set`. Why is the IDE confused?

Comment: Not sure what you mean, but I can see that you need to remove the extra { that comes after public int Age; Ok nvm I think you are trying to create auto properties? i.e. public int Age { get; set;} ?

Comment: maybe delete the First curly-brace ?

Comment: take out the ; after Age

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should remove `;` after "Age".

It is:

```
internal class Person
{
    private int age;
    public int Age { set; get; }
}
```

Comment: this answer is 100% correct - why is it marked down

Comment: thanks! what a terrible error. This is the exact answer i want, why vote down?

Comment: I wonder why i got this "minus".

Comment: Dunno why -1? Possibly because you didn't have the code explaining it?

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
internal class Person
{
    private int age;
    public int Age { set; get; }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

The more complete answer is that you've ended the field `Age` and the IDE is reading what you've written and is expecting a Type (among a few other contextually based options, of which `set` is NOT one). You've only written `set`, and the best match for `set` for a type in the given context is `AppDomainSetup` because it is the first Type in whose name the substring `set` is found. The autocomplete behavior is to input the selected suggestion when you press space.

To correct this (or to stop confusing intellisense), don't put a colon after the property name.

```
public int Age { set // and continue typing
```